# Spark Coalesce : when by mistake more partition value is passed in parameter

Tags: apache-spark

Not very sure how this code will behave, let's assume we have 12 partitions and then we are trying to do
`df = df.coalesce(24) #increasing the partition`

1. once this is executed, will it create 24 partitions ? I have deliberately kept it more, I know coalesce is meant to decrease the partitions.
2. or it will decrease the partition randomly, and the final partition will be less than 12?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an extract of the documentation of the `coalesce` function:

> Returns a new Dataset that has exactly numPartitions partitions, when the fewer partitions are requested. If a larger number of partitions is requested, it will stay at the current number of partitions.

So `df.coalesce(24)` will return a dataframe with 12 partitions if `df` has 12 partitions.

You can try it with the spark shell:

```scala
scala> spark.range(100).repartition(12).rdd.getNumPartitions
res0: Int = 12

scala> spark.range(100).repartition(12).coalesce(24).rdd.getNumPartitions
res1: Int = 12
```